# Forge viewer integration with Potree

Tags: autodesk-forge, point-clouds, autodesk-viewer

is there any documentation or example for forge viewer to integrate the point cloud visualisation lib Potree with Forge viewer?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such example today. There is [a thread](https://github.com/potree/potree/issues/28) on Potree github website talking about what is needed to support Potree on Three.js and since the Forge Viewer is based on Three.js it still applies since the Forge Viewer is written on an older version of Three.js which is compatible with that thread.

Comment: Hi @Cyrille thanks for the response. With this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pix4d/three-potree-loader, Potree can be accessed in a isolated and modularised way. But in order to make it work in Forge viewer, I think we need a way to hook the rendering loop. Is there any event to listen with when it triggers re-rendering

Comment: - Is there any event to hook the rendering loop in order to add a new rendering scene with the pointcloud (this is the way we used to do with other version of THREE.js)

Not exactly custom scenes, but you can insert custom objects either into `viewer.impl.scene`, or by creating an overlay scene.
Alternatively, you can use the new utility wrapper (https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-viewer-utils) to add custom geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an experimental branch of [potree-core](https://github.com/tentone/potree-core) that's been back-ported to three.js v71 (the one used by Forge Viewer): https://github.com/petrbroz/potree-core/tree/experiment/three71.

And here's a demo of the potree loader used in Forge Viewer: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo.

Comment: I realize that the depth buffer related to EDL shading seems not working in this version. Is that a restriction for the three.js v71?